# TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__' tkinter error

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

The issue I am having here is that whenever I try to input data into my Username entry box (`self.KUEntry.get()`) and run the input from that box within my query, it returns none and throws the error listed in the question.

The function is supposed to check the stored salt and hash of a registered user and compare it with the password that they are typing into the entry box.

```
def login_verification(self):

    username = self.KUEntry.get()
    print username

    cursor1.execute = ("SELECT salt FROM User WHERE username = (%s)", username)
    salty = cursor1.fetchone() [0]
    print salty

    cursor2.execute = ("SELECT PashHash FROM User WHERE username = %s", (username))
    hashy = cursor2.fetchone() [0]
    print hashy

    test = hashlib.sha512(username + salty).hexdigest
    print test

    if test == hashy:
        self.mainscreen
    else:
        print "incorrect password"
```

Comment: That is a  common problem. I am sure we can help you if you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I think you are simply missing single quotes around the username within the sql statement: `... WHERE username = '%s'`

Comment: Where is the traceback?

Comment: This is the traceback:

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "./Uninote.py", line 104, in login_verification
    salty = cursor1.fetchone() [0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__

Comment: and unfortunately adding single quotes does not resolve the issue either. The error is coming on the fetchone method

Answer (score 0):

Putting my code like this fixes the traceback error, but it does not return what is expected. Instead of my cursor1.fetchone and cursor2.fetchone methods returning the result of the query they return "none".

```
def login_verification(self):

    username = self.KUEntry.get()
    print username

    cursor1.execute = ("SELECT salt FROM User WHERE username = %s", str(username))
    salty = str(cursor1.fetchone())
    print salty

    cursor2.execute = ("SELECT PashHash FROM User WHERE username = %s", str(username))
    hashy = str(cursor2.fetchone())
    print hashy

    test = hashlib.sha512(username + str(salty)).hexdigest
    print test

    if test == hashy:
        self.mainscreen
    else:
        print "incorrect password"
```